# I have used daterange picker in the form how can I disable particular date range which is fetching from MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i have to disable the multiple date range.

functions i have used as follows

```js
function myCallback(start, end) {
  console.log("callback");

  $("#dateRange_n").html(
    start.format("MM DD, YYYY") + " - " + end.format("MM D, YYYY")
  );
}

let options = {
  startDate: "12-01-2018",
  endDate: "12-01-2023",
  minDate: "10-06-2021",
  isInvalidDate: function(ele) {
    var compareDate = moment(ele);
    var startDate = moment("12/01/2019", "DD/MM/YYYY");
    var endDate = moment("5/06/2021", "DD/MM/YYYY");
    return compareDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate);
  },
};

$("#dateRange_n").daterangepicker(options, myCallback);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
<div class="form-group" id="input-dates">
  <input class="form-control date-range-picker" id="dateRange_n" type="text" name="dates" placeholder="test...." autocomplete="off" required />
  <i class="icon_calendar"></i>
</div>
```

```
<?php  
    $this->db->select('booking_date');
  $this->db->where('listing_id', $listing_details['id']);
  $records = $this->db->get('booking');
    $res = $records->result_array();  ?>
```

where i get $res as follows:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [booking_date] => 2021-06-05 - 2021-06-06 ) [1] => Array ( [booking_date] => 2021-06-15 - 2021-06-16 ) [2] => Array ( [booking_date] => 2021-06-17 - 2021-06-18 ) [3] => Array ( [booking_date] => 2021-06-19 - 2021-06-20 ) )
```

here i have to fetch the date range from mysql database & disable it

Comment: You should show how you fetch data from Mysql and how you connect it.

Comment: @ikhvjs i have edited my question can you please help me

Comment: Hi, you actually have a arrays and you can use this function  ```compareDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate)``` and one item in the array suppose to return a ```boolean``` value. What you need to do just return a result of all ```compareDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate)```. 
For example, you have arrays of 4 date object. you suppose to have 4 result of ```compareDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate)```. After you get 4 results, you return them in the ```isInvalidDate```, such as ```return result1 || result2 || result3 || result 4```. I hope it helps you to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create my own table because you did not provide one in your question, but you should be able to change the SQL statement to get the proper start and end date and it will work for you.

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH0u8.png)

```
<div class="form-group" id="input-dates">
  <input class="form-control date-range-picker" id="dateRange_n" type="text" name="dates" placeholder="test...." autocomplete="off" required />
  <i class="icon_calendar"></i>
</div>

<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "root"; /* User */
$password = ""; /* Password */
$dbname = "test"; /* Database name */

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


     $sql = "SELECT * FROM date";

     $result = $conn->query($sql);
       
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,$sql));

     $startDate = $row['startDate'];

     $endDate = $row['endDate'];

?>

<script>
    function myCallback(start, end) {
  console.log("callback");

  $("#dateRange_n").html(
    start.format("MM DD, YYYY") + " - " + end.format("MM D, YYYY")
  );
}

let options = {
  startDate: "12-01-2018",
  endDate: "12-01-2023",
  minDate: "10-06-2021",
  isInvalidDate: function(ele) {
    var compareDate = moment(ele);
    var startDate = moment("<?php echo $startDate ?>", "DD/MM/YYYY");
    var endDate = moment("<?php echo $endDate ?>", "DD/MM/YYYY");
    return compareDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate);
  },
};

$("#dateRange_n").daterangepicker(options, myCallback);
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, but i get my sql result in number of rows so how can i use foreach for the start date & enddate

Comment: Are you printing the Date Range Selector multiple times? @PriyankaPatil

Comment: @PriyankaPatil Can you edit your question to show us how you are retrieving the SQL results?

Comment: yes i have edited the question with mysql query & it's result set